# conditions on Fourier Transform of derivative

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

At page 445 of Myint-U's Linear Partial Differential Equations (4th Ed), Fourier Tranform of derivative is defined as: Let $f$ be a continuous and piecewise smooth in $(-\infty, \infty)$. Let $f(x)$ approach zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. If $f$ and $f'$ are absolutey integrable, then $$\mathcal{F}[f'(x)] = \imath\, k \, \mathcal{F}[f(x)] = \imath\, k \, F(k). $$ In expansion of LHS we get this step: $$\mathcal{F}[f'(x)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{- \imath\, k\, x} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \left[ f(x) e^{- \imath\, k \, x}\;  |_{-\infty}^{\infty}\quad + \cdots \right].$$ We can find functions such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) =0$ $\;$ but $\;$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) e^{- \imath\, k \, x} \neq 0$. Example is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.
Obviously for $f(x)$ satisfying rest of the conditions (continuity and smoothness etc) the required limit does go to zero. Example $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$.
**My question**: How can we prove (generally) that the term $f(x) e^{- \imath\, k \, x}$ goes to zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ when all conditions are met.

Comment: I believe that the property of the derivative of the Fourier Transform requires that $\left[f(x)\,e^{-ikx} \right]\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty = 0$ as is explained in [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html) site for the Fourier Transform, which is not true in general, but is true for "many" functions, at least for bounded functions with existent Fourier Transform as is explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponential with purely imaginary argument has absolute value equal to 1 so it is sufficient that $f$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Many thanks for quick answer. It seems, I was set off on wrong footings ignoring the "iota". Now I observe that, example I have quoted $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is incorrect. It is all clear now. Many thanks agian.